# Digital Signature Password verification

Tags: signature, protocol-design, authentication, passwords, nonce

I currently have this [TOFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) protocol:

First connection:

1. Client generates [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) and inputs a password
2. Client saves salt
3. Client hashes password with [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) and salt
4. Client generates [Ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) keys
5. Client sends to the server: Ed25519 public key, argon2 hashed password
6. Server saves received Ed25519 public key and argon2 hashed password

After first connection:

1. Server sends to client a newly generated [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)
2. Client receives nonce inputs a password
3. Client hashes the password with argon2 (salt is retrieved from file), then the nonce is appended to it, then the result of the append is hashed with [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), then the final hash is signed with a Ed25519 [private key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
4. Client sends [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) to server
5. Server verifies with the Ed25519 [public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) (Ed25519 public key is retrieved from file) and argon2 hashed password (argon2 hashed password is retrieved from file) which also goes through the SHA-2 with the nonce which was earlier generated and sent

So my question is, is this protocol secure to verify the user has both the Ed25519 private key and the correct password? If yes is there a way to keep the same level of security while making it simpler, also is the SHA-2 necessary in after connection step 2? If not what are the flaws and how do you recommend to fix them?

Also, does a protocol like this already exist?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the proposition that someone knows the password and Ed25519 private key?  Are you going to have a conversation with them, so that what you really want is an authenticated key agreement?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage my goal is to have an authenticated conversation, I am currently using Signal Protocol and reading about [authentication with nonce][https://signal.org/docs/specifications/sesame/#protecting-server-communications] and I wanted to add a password into the mix.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to sign the outcome of a PAKE with the Ed25519 key, since presumably you would want to ensure that even if an adversary compromised the Ed25519 key, a transcript of the network interaction of a MITM attack wouldn't help them to guess the password offline.

Comment: Well yes, but I also want to make sure, if a password was compromised an attacker still can't be authenticated since he also must have the Ed25519 private key from the registration.

Comment: Hence ‘sign the outcome of a PAKE with the Ed25519 key’ so that you reject authentication attempts if they do not prove ownership of the Ed25519 key.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I am sorry but I was wrong, I looked more into what PAKE is, and first time I read about I missed the point where it is for establishing cryptographic keys and not authenticating passwords, I don't need a cryptographic key, this is over SSL I only need authentication based on a password

Comment: From your description, you seem to be looking for a way to simultaneously agree on a session key for a conversation, prove knowledge of a password, and prove knowledge of an Ed25519 private key, no?  The first two (simultaneously agree on a key and prove knowledge of a password, _i.e._ authenticated key agreement with a password) are exactly what a PAKE does.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage No, I am not looking to generate a session key based on a password since this is over SSL which already is encrypted. After a successful handshake occurs I need the server to know I am who I claim to be by proving I have the password and the Ed25519 private key. Also just some clarification encase you're unaware Signal Protocol is E2E so I am looking to get a session key but with another user which is what Signal Protocol will do, I am not looking for a PAKE protocol to help me. I only need the server to authenticate a user so a malicious party cannot impersonate a user.